# Enumerating a list that follows the number of the Theorem, Lemma, etc

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I want to make a list looking like something like this.

Theorem3.2 The set has the following properties:

(3.2.1) Nonempty.

(3.2.2) Compact.

I don't know if there is a way to convert regular enumerate command into something like this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s flexibility to specify the `label` to include `\thetheorem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}% Just for this example
\section{A section}

\setcounter{theorem}{1}% Just for this example
\begin{theorem}
  The set has the following parameters:
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\thetheorem.\arabic*)},leftmargin=*]
    \item Non-empty and
    \item Compact.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhh clever! You could just define a new environment, like `thmenum` or so, that included this...